# asp .net mvc postdata always 0 in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, form-data

I have very simple code (asp .net mvc c#) but just couldn't make it work. The companyId is always zero, while the booleans are returning correctly. My postdata is class called SomeObj with the ff properties

```
public bool isSomeBoolean1 { get; set; }
        public bool isSomeBoolean2 { get; set; }
        public bool isSomeBoolean3{ get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
```

js:

```
var formData = formModule.createFormData(containerSelector + someContainer, false);
        formData.append("companyId", $("#myCompanyId").val());

        var promise = baseAjaxWithUpload('/SomeController/SomeAction', 'POST', formData).execute();

        promise.done(function (operationStatus) {
            if (operationStatus.isSuccess) {

            }


        });
```

The boolean properties returns correctly according to my input in form, but not CompanyId. I have tried wrapping it in JSON.stringify, made the companyId string type, put it back to int but parseInt(CompanyId) before passing. I also made the "CompanyId" to "companyId" but nothing worked.

I made sure that the formdata has value coz I typed in console *formData.get("CompanyId") or formData.get("companyId")* when I changed it to that spelling, both have values, but turns to zero in the controller.

I have also tried doing this:

```
var data = {
            CompanyId: $("#myCompanyId").val(),
            isSomeBoolean1 : true,
            isSomeBoolean2 : true,
            isSomeBoolean2: false,

        }

 var promise = baseAjaxWithUpload('/SomeController/SomeAction', 'POST', JSON.stringify(data) ).execute();
```

all booleans are passed correctly in controller just like formData, but not companyid. it always is 0;

this is my controller that uses it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomAction(SomeObj  someObj )
{

}
```

I have also tried isolating the issue by adding a property called CompanyIdString with type string, then put hardcoded values like this formData.append("companyIdString", "test"), and tried to peek the value thru get, and it has, but that string returns null in controller. I also tried upper case spelling.

I mean I have been passing companyId all over the app, and never had a problem until now. What am I missing?

Comment: I figured it out, such stupid mistake. formData.append("SomeObj.CompanyId", 1) did the trick. The answer below is othe same as what's being called in BaseAjaxWithFileUpload so I know the result will be the same. tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type in the AJAX call:

```
var data = {
        CompanyId: $("#myCompanyId").val(),
        isSomeBoolean1 : true,
        isSomeBoolean2 : true,
        isSomeBoolean2: false,

    }

 $.ajax({
 url: 'myUrl',
 type: "POST",
 contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 data: data,
 success: function (result) {
     console.log(result);
 }
```

});